# updated ubuntu 12.04...wireless is not working after that

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I have new Dell inspiron 15 lappy with Ubuntu 12.04.Updated it.But after updating, wireless is not working.I have qualcomm atheros wireless adaptor in it.Please help.

Comment: Please enter on to terminal and type lspci and press enter. Copy and paste here result.

Comment: 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: Nikhil - if it was you who tried to respond via an answer - please click the contact-us link at the bottom of this page with your registered account and then request an account merge with your unregistered account.  Once done you will be able to re-edit your question with further details.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please obtain a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc.tar.bz2
tar xvf compat*
cd compat-wireless-3.6.6-1-snpc
sudo -i
./scripts/driver-select ath9k
make
make install
modprobe ath9k
exit
```

Your wireless should now be working.